# How To Load Separate NIB/Class Using UISegmentedController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 separate view controllers with their own NIB file.

I have a overview view in my app with a segmented control that you can toggle through. Instead of copying all 3 of these view's methods and putting them into this overview's class, is it possible to just load each view as a subview of the overview view deepening on which segment is selected?

```
- (void)segmentedControl:(SVSegmentedControl*)segmentedControl didSelectIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            MusclesTableViewController *musclesTableViewController = [[MusclesTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MusclesTableViewController" bundle:nil]; 
            [self.view addSubview: musclesTableViewController]; 
            [musclesTableViewController release];  
        }
            break;
        case 1:
            // load second nib and add it as a subview    
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect an action to your segment controller:

```
[yourSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSegment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

use your method to load the desired subview:

```
- (void)changeSegment:(id)sender {
    UISegmentedControl *segment = sender;

    switch ([segment selectedSegmentIndex]) {
        case 1:
            // load first nib and add it as a subview
        break;
        case 2:
            // load second nib and add it as a subview    
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: The segment I'm using actually only has this delegate method, can you fit this into your code? Thanks. `- (void)segmentedControl:(SVSegmentedControl*)segmentedControl didSelectIndex:(NSUInteger)index`

Comment: you can use switch to add a subview according to selected segment index.

Comment: Ok, ill do that, can you show how to load the nib and add as subview? then ill accept answer. thanks.

Comment: This could be find with a simple search on the site. BTW YourViewController *controller = [[YourViewController alloc]
             initWithNibName:@"YourViewControllerNibFile" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:controller];
[controller release];

Comment: Thanks, I added code to my question.  I tried that but nothing is happening.

Comment: did you try to add a breakpoint to the switch and see what's happening?